# Protect view of Dash app embedded in Flask app authenticated with MSAL

Tags: python, authentication, flask, plotly-dash, azure-ad-msal

**The Issue:**

I have a Flask application with a Dash app embedded. I added MSAL authentication to the flask app, but I can still go directly to `local_host:5000/dash` and see my dashboard without logging in. My goal is to protect that dashboard.

For my authentication process, I referenced https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp
pretty heavily. The approach is to redirect users who haven't logged in back to the login screen instead of permitting them to go to a screen requiring authentication like so:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not session.get("user"):
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template('index.html', user=session["user"], version=msal.__version__)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    session["state"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    # Technically we could use empty list [] as scopes to do just sign in,
    # here we choose to also collect end user consent upfront
    auth_url = _build_auth_url(scopes=app_config.SCOPE, state=session["state"])
    return render_template("login.html", auth_url=auth_url, version=msal.__version__)
```

The only real change I need to make is to the repository is to the `app.py` file by add the following:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

dashapp = dash.Dash(__name__, server=app, url_base_pathname='/dash/')
dashapp.layout = html.Div([html.H1('Hi there')])
```

With that added, we have our minimal example. Unfortunately, as previously mentioned, I can get to `local_host:5000/dash`. I want that URL to exist, but I want it to be protected by the authentication.

**What I've Tried:**

I tried making a route for the dashboard:

```
@app.route("/dash")
def dashboard():
    if not session.get("user"):
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return <*NOT SURE*>
```

I'm not 100% sure what I would return here. I've tried a couple things like `redirect("\dash")`, but it doesn't matter because this route never gets called. It doesn't overwrite the Dash url base pathname.

I've seen others suggest a `_protect_dashviews` approach:

```
from flask_login import login_required

def _protect_dashviews(dashapp):
    for view_func in dashapp.server.view_functions:
        url_base_pathname = dashapp.config.requests_pathname_prefix
        if url_base_pathname is None:
            url_base_pathname = '/'
        if view_func.startswith(url_base_pathname):
            dashapp.server.view_functions[view_func] = login_required(dashapp.server.view_functions[view_func])
            
_protect_dashviews(dashapp)
```

This does keep me from getting to the `/dash` URL, but it has an error because the login_required isn't connected to my authentication process. From what I can tell, it's designed to work with the LoginManager found in that same package. Maybe there is a way to make it work with my authentication, but I can't find it.

I've spend a few days on this, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated! I'm open to altering my authentication process (though it needs to use MSAL), restructuring, disabling or overwriting the Dash url, etc. Whatever is possible works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got a very hacky, very simple solution. For me, UX isn't a problem, I just need unauthorized users kept out for nearly every path.

```
@server.before_request
def requires_authorisation():
    allowed_routes = ['/robots.txt', '/login', '/callback', '/']
    if 'profile' not in session and request.path not in allowed_routes:
      return redirect('/login')
```

/login redirects to our login page and /callback populates the profile after login.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: Edited to provide my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is over a year old, but here is how I hacked this into working. First create a decorator module to wrap your route with the log in check. I called it decorator.py

````
import flask
from functools import wraps

def login_required(f):
    """
    Decorator for flask endpoints, ensuring that the user is authenticated and redirecting to log-in page if not.
    Example:
    ```
        from flask import current_app as app
        @login_required
        @app.route("/")
        def index():
            return 'route protected'
    ```
    """
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):

        if not flask.session.get("user"):
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('login'))
        
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
````

You may need to change the string in 'flask.url_for()' to redirect to your login page. Then in your dash application add the following function. This function is similar to what OP has, but does not require Login Manager.

```
def protect_dashviews(dash_app):
    for view_func in dash_app.server.view_functions:
        if view_func.startswith(dash_app.config.routes_pathname_prefix):
            dash_app.server.view_functions[view_func] = login_required(dash_app.server.view_functions[view_func])
```

If you are using an older version of Dash, you may need to replace 'dash_app.config.routes_pathname_prefix' with 'dash_app.config.url_base_pathname'. What I believe this function is doing is wrapping the dash apps route that is unseen with the decorator module we made.

In your dash application, also add import the login_required function from the decorator and add the protect_dashviews() function after you initialize your app. It should look something similar to this.

```
from where_the_decorator_module_is import login_required
...
app = dash.Dash(
        server=server,
        routes_pathname_prefix='/url/to/app/',
)
protect_dashviews(app)
```

I figured this out from the following article https://andysprague.com/2020/11/11/flask-blueprint-for-microsoft-azure-aad-authentication-oauth-2-0/. I've cut out much of the stuff I didn't need.